# How to set Payload for Recipient List Group Endpoint?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a sequence that is invoking multiple endpoints. My sequence is:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="GetAllData">
   <switch xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:cct="http://www.tempuri.org" xmlns:tns="http://www.tempuri.org" source="//tns:IDFilter/cct:ID">
      <case regex=".?">
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Property2" value="----------------Inside switch 1 ? ---------------"/>
         </log>
         <filter xpath="//tns:ChildIDFilter/cct:ID='?'">
            <then>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="prop1" value="------Inside Then------------------"/>
               </log>
               **<payloadFactory>
                  <format>
                     <select_all_ID_operation xmlns:cir="http://tempuri.org"/>
                  </format>
               </payloadFactory>
               <payloadFactory>
                  <format>
                     <select_all_ChildID_operation xmlns="http://tempuri.org"/>
                  </format>
               </payloadFactory>
               <send>
                  <endpoint key="ID_Service_EPS"/>
               </send>**
            </then>
            <else>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="prop2" value="------Inside Else------------------"/>
               </log>
               <payloadFactory>
                  <format>
                     <select_all_ID_operation xmlns="http://tempuri.org"/>
                  </format>
               </payloadFactory>
               <send receive="ValidateAllData">
                  <endpoint key="ID_Endpoint"/>
               </send>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </case>
   </switch>
</sequence>
```

Now in my ID_EPS endpoint, i have two wsdl endpoints and for them i have to pass payload to get data from both wsdl's, but this is not happenning. My question is how to invoke recipient endpoint contaning different wsdl Endpoints and setting payload for it and finally get the concatinated result. Looking forward to your answers.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the management console-->endpoint menu, you can find the recipient list endpoint, where provide your both endpoints, and refer that recipient endpoint from your sequence

Answer (score 0):

To send messages to two endpoints (in your case two wsdl endpoints) using recipient list endpoint, the message format accepted by both endpoints should be identical.

If so, you can send messages to both endpoints using a recipient list endpoint and then aggregate the response messages and construct the concatenated result.
Refer to following resource to find a sample configuration of Recipient list endpoint.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Sample+62%3A+Routing+a+Message+to+a+Dynamic+List+of+Recipients+and+Aggregating+Responses

If two endpoint message formats are not identical, you have to implement a service chaining scenario or you can clone the message and create two different branches for two endpoints and construct the payload required by each service endpoint and send to the service endpoint within that branch. Then you can aggregate the responses received from both branches and construct the concatenated result.

Comment: can you provide me an example of service chaining that i can apply for above problem?